# Add conditional columns and custom value columns to database-linked query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, data-structures

TL;DR version: I have a query linked to a database. I need to add some columns to it for data that isn't linked to the database, but don't know how.

I'm quite new to SQL and Access (got a reasonable grasp of Excel and VBA though) and have a pretty complex reporting task. I've got halfway (I think) but am stuck.

**Purpose**
A report showing how many (or what percentage of) delivery lines were late in a time period, with reasons for their being late from a set list, and analysis of what's the biggest cause of lateness.

**Vague Plan**
Create a table/query showing delivery lines with customer, required date and delivery date, plus a column to show whether they were on time, plus another to detail lateness reason. Summaries can be done afterwards in Excel. I'd like to be able to cycle through said table in form view entering lateness reasons (they'll be from a linked table, maybe 4 or 5 options).

**Sticking Point**
I have the data, but not the analysis. I've created the original data output query, it's linked to a live SQL database (Orderwise) so it keeps updating. However I don't know:

- how to add extra columns and lookups to that to figure / record whether it's ontime and lateness reason
- how I'll be able to cycle through the late ones in form view to add reasons

How do I structure the access database so it can do this please?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: I suggest you add sample data for both existing data and what you want to achieve. At the moment it is quite unclear what that could be. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).